# Disable Image Link Hover underline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, image, hover

Just made a semi-transparent image into a link in my rails App

```
<%= link_to image_tag("cow.png"), cows_path %>
```

The actual image, however, doesn't take up a perfect rectangle, because of its transparency, and when I hover over it with my mouse, it creates a black bar the width of the image rectangle below the image, protruding from either side of the non-transparent part of the image.

The question is how to get this hover behavior to stop.

[image: The Link Image]

The transparent image is of the cow, and the black bar there is the problem. The tan stuff is the page background, not the image.

Any ideas? I just don't know the CSS command to fix this.

EDIT: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2AKDa/1) . Sorry. Was away from my computer for a bit. I included some of the suggestions, but they don't seem to be fixing things. I may also be doing it wrong. This is a css.scss stylesheet.

Comment: not clear to get. can you plz give a demo link in jsfiddle.net for quickly get the correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing that worked for me was to put this in the .animal-buttons class:

```
a {
background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you give us the generated HTML, we have to assume thisngs. Just use this:

```
a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
a img {border: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the lack of your actual HTML, it is shot in the dark, but you can try these CSS rules:

```
img {border:0;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:focus {outline:0;}

a:hover {text-decoration:none; outline:0;}

img, img:hover {border:0; outline:0;}
```